# How does apple's app refer work?

Tags: ios

Some apps generate a link you can send to people to get some sort of credit (ingame currency, gems, etc.) once they download the app via the link you sent. How does the game know your refer id eg. link.com?ref=x how is x kept through the process of them downloading the app and sent to their servers, is it stored in safari cookies?

Comment: Using deep linking in app.

Comment: normally [ASIdentifierManager.advertisingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier), which is part of the AdSupport framework